# Listbox with multiple columns wpf

Tags: wpf, listbox, multiple-columns

I want to show multiple columns in the list box. I have referred the following link [Using WrapPanel and ScrollViewer to give a multi-column Listbox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908089/using-wrappanel-and-scrollviewer-to-give-a-multi-column-listbox-in-wpf).

Problem:

I want to scroll the content using repeat button. How to control the listbox scrollbar using button.

Code:

```
  <ListBox Name="lbTrack" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" Margin="10" Text="{Binding TrackName}" />                                    </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical"></WrapPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that will work fine. Is there a problem you're having with it?

EDIT: In response to the updated question... In order to programmatically scroll the ListBox you can use the UI Automation framework. Below is some Silverlight code that I found that should work for WPF as well.

```
var automationPeer = FrameworkElementAutomationPeer.FromElement(element) ??
                     FrameworkElementAutomationPeer.CreatePeerForElement(element);

var scrollProvider = automationPeer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Scroll) as IScrollProvider;
if (scrollProvider != null) {
    scrollProvider.Scroll(horizontalScrollAmount, verticalScrollAmount);
}
```

It may also be possible to get this to work by pointing the [ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.scrollbar.lineleftcommand.aspx) and [ScrollBar.LineRightCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.scrollbar.linerightcommand.aspx) at the ScrollViewer nested in the ListBox's template but I wasn't able to get that working and I don't know if you could do that without code anyway.